# php5 usage of preg_match

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am using php5 using preg_match() to extract the data on match. Previously we were using lower version of php5 and were using ereg() for the same purpose.

Below is the code using ereg:

```
$wedge =shell_exec("iwinfo wlan0 info");
$pattern1='ESSID: "([^\]*)"';
ereg($pattern1, $wedge, $SSID);
```

So **$SSID** was containging the SSID of the AP.

Now I changed to preg_match() but I am not able to extract it. This is the way :

```
$wedge =shell_exec("iwinfo wlan0 info");
$pattern1='ESSID: "([^\]*)"';
echo preg_match('/$pattern1/', $wedge, $SSID);
```

Can anyone help me how to extract SSID in a complete string by giving start and end of the string?

Update: The output of the iwinfo wlan0 info will be like this:

```
wlan0     ESSID: "Openwrt"
```

So the output of $SSID I am expecting is *Openwrt*.

Regards,
Sowmya

Comment: Carrefull, the simple quote don't execute the PHP. So `'/$pattern1/'` is literraly interperted. Note : the ereg function use POSIX syntaxe and preg_match use PCRE syntax. It's not the same http://php.net/manual/fr/book.regex.php 
http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pcre.php

Comment: what is the value of `$SSID`? and what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Also note that `$SSID` will be an array when you use `preg_match()` so you need to extract the required data from that array to get your  SSID.

Comment: Can you add the value of $wedge and the expected values of $SSID please?

Comment: I have updated my question regarding the output of SSID.

Answer (score 2):

1. In php, text wrapped by single quotes is not evaluated, so `'/$pattern1/'` means literally `/$pattern1/`, not `/ESSID: "([^\]*)"/`;
2. `ESSID: "([^\]*)"` is not valid regular expression: the backslash is an escape character, so it escape following `]`, but by this way previous `[` remains opened. The correct syntax is `[^\]]*` and it means: “search zero-or-more chars except closing square bracket”, but I don't think you are in search of this, seeing your string;
3. `preg_match()` return 1 if a match is found, 0 if not, False if the pattern is not valid. The matched values are stored not in result, but in third optional argument, an array.

So, you can use this syntax:

```
$pattern1 = '/ESSID: "([^"]*)"/';
preg_match( $pattern1, $wedge, $SSID );
echo $SSID[1];
```

and the output is:

```
Openwrt
```

<kbd>**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nX4xF3/1)**</kbd>

Pattern explained:

```
/
ESSID:      # literally “ESSID: ”
"           # double quote
([^"]*)     # Group 1: zero-or-more characters except double quote
"           # double quote
/
```

Using not-greedy operator, you can simplify the pattern in this way:

```
/ESSID: "(.*?)"/
```

`(.*?)` means: zero-or-more chars except following in pattern (in your case, double quote).

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working. Thank you for the link of online tool for php and for the explanation of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The manual for [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) says:

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

So, your `echo preg_match('/$pattern1/', $wedge, $SSID);` doesn't do anything useful. Now, PHP also doesn't recognize your variables (or regex) in single quotes, so that must be changed to double quotes:

`preg_match("/$pattern1/", $wedge, $SSID)`

Try a `var_dump()` on `$SSID`, see what that returns. If it doesn't return anything, please ask a new question relating to your regex.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 16

Comment: You escape the closing `]` by prefixing it with a backslash ` \\ `. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this code.

```
$wedge    = shell_exec( "iwinfo wlan0 info" );
$pattern1 = 'ESSID: "([^\]*)"';
$output   =  preg_match( '/$pattern1/', $wedge, $SSID, , PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

print_r( $output );
```

Comment: The preg_match is returning 0 which means it dint found the string.